# JOLT - Merge Nested Child into parent

Tags: json, jolt

**JSON Input:**

```
[
  {
    "Rating": 1,
    "SecondaryRatings": {
      "Design": 4,
      "Price": 2,
      "RatingDimension3": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "Rating": 1,
    "SecondaryRatings": {
      "Design": 4,
      "Price": 2,
      "RatingDimension3": 1
    }
  }
]
```

**JOLT Spec:**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Rating": "[&1].rating-primary",
        "SecondaryRatings": {
          "*": "rating-&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Current output:**

```
 [ {
      "rating-primary" : 1
    }, {
      "rating-primary" : 1
    } ]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[ {
  "rating-primary" : 1
  "rating-Design" : 4,
  "rating-Price" : 2,
  "rating-RatingDimension3" : 1
}, {
  "rating-primary" : 1
  "rating-Design" : 4,
  "rating-Price" : 2,
  "rating-RatingDimension3" : 1

} ]
```

Comment: @milo-s ... hope you have a quick answer for this? :)
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2540376/milo-s 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Rating": "[&1].rating-primary",
        "SecondaryRatings": {
          "*": "[&2].rating-&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```